# WPF Progressbar won't left align properly

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, alignment, progress-bar

i have the following XAML code to display a set of controls in my window:

```
<Grid Height="80">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Width="80" />

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Titel}"
               Foreground="#B0B0B0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,0" Text="{Binding Description}" Foreground="#c9c9c9"
               VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <ProgressBar Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Value="50" Margin="5" Height="15" MaxWidth="200" />

</Grid>
```

Its basically an Image to the left and two TextBlocks and a ProgressBar to the right.

My problem is that the ProgressBar at the end will stretch infinitely wide when my window gets wider.
I want my progressbar to stop growing at a certain point. So if the user stretches the window it will stop at a given MaxWidth.
So i tried this:

```
<ProgressBar Grid.Row="2" Value="50" Margin="5" Height="15" MaxWidth="200"/>
```

But this will center the ProgressBar in the middle of the window if it is stretched more than MaxWidth generating space between the Image on the left and the ProgressBar.
I want the Progressbar to stick to the left but `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` minimizes the ProgressBar to a few pixels:

```
<ProgressBar Grid.Row="2" Value="50" Margin="5" Height="15" MaxWidth="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

Does anyone have an idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also wrap your `ProgressBar` in a `Grid` with two columns defined as below:

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MaxWidth="200"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ProgressBar Grid.Column="0" Value="50" Margin="5" Height="15"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try binding to the width of the other element:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="title" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Titel}" Foreground="#B0B0B0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

<ProgressBar Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Value="50" Margin="5" Height="15" Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=title}" MaxWidth="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```